# signal points to slot in struct

Tags: qt, struct, connection, signals-slots

I'd like a signal to be connected to a slot inside of a struct. My struct looks like:

```
//Header file

struct someStruct {
    public:
        int index;

    public slots:
        void someSlot();
};

QList<someStruct*> mListOfStructs;
```

and then I create a button that should forward its `clicked()` signal to the `someSlot` function.

```
//Source file

QPushButton *cmd = new QPushButton();
grd->addWidget(cmd, 3, 2, Qt::AlignCenter);
//grd is a QGridLayout somewhere inside the gui. I can see it and also the button.
```

now connection the `clicked()` event with the slot inside a specific struct does not work.

```
connect(cmd, SIGNAL(clicked()), mListOfStructs[3], SLOT(someSlot()));
```

some sources tell me that I have to add a metaObject or sth. I tried but it didn't work out. Maybe you know better.

I might use [How to connect in Qt signal and slot in dynamically added buttons to get in slot index of added button?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45265391/6649601) as workaround though.

Comment: Apart from anything else you've forgotten your [`Q_OBJECT`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT) macro in the `someStruct` struct definition.

Comment: @G.M. `Q_OBJECT` is needed for signals slots :D, yes. Maybe first step to get it work.

Comment: ...I am not getting through. Implementing workaround now :(

Comment: what? why not? what error you get?

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ ERROR while putting `public slots:` after `public:` : `Parse error at ";"` -> `[moc_popupMessages.cpp] Error 1` and ERROR when putting `public:` after `public slots` : `In static member function bla::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**))` -> `class bla has no member named someSlot` -> `[moc_bla.o] Error 1`

Comment: Did you try the example below in the given answer ???

Comment: yes I did right now

Answer (score 0):

your structure need the Q_Object meta attributes in order to emit signals and recieve slot events...

```
struct testStruct : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        int index;
        testStruct():index(0){}

    public slots:
        void someSlot()
        {
            qDebug() << "slot called!";
        }
};
```

after that you can conected as usual:

```
testStruct *ts= new testStruct;
connect(this, SIGNAL(someSignal()), ts, SLOT(someSlot()));
```